# PHPMyAdmin 500 Internal Server Error in Apache

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

**Version:**

- OS `lsb_release -a` : Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
- PHP `php -v` : 8.0.1
- Apache `apache2 -v` : 2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
- MySQL `mysql -v` : 10.1.47-MariaDB

---

**Problem:**

I'm trying to install LAMP Stack using following [article](https://www.tecmint.com/install-lamp-with-phpmyadmin-in-ubuntu-20-04/). However, I was getting `HTTP 500 Error` while accessing `phpmyadmin` from browser.

So, I tried to create symlink using `ln` command but it fails

> ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf': File exists

```
root@host:/etc/phpmyadmin# sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf': File exists
```

---

**Tried 1:**

Then, I'd created symlink by forcing `ln -sf`.

- `sudo ln -sf /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf`

And run the following command

- `sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin.conf`
- `sudo systemctl reload apache2.service`

```
root@host:/etc/phpmyadmin# ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     2110 Jul 10  2017 apache.conf
```

```
root@host:/etc/apache2/conf-available# ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Jan 30 06:52 phpmyadmin.conf -> ../../phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

---

**Tried 2:**

I even reconfigured phpmyadmin if incase I bymistakely didn't select **apache2** using

- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin`

---

`/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf`

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration

Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        <IfModule mod_mime.c>
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        </IfModule>
        <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
            SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
        </FilesMatch>

        php_value include_path .
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
        php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/phpseclib/
        php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 0
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_php.c>
        <IfModule mod_mime.c>
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        </IfModule>
        <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
            SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
        </FilesMatch>

        php_value include_path .
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
        php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/phpseclib/
        php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 0
    </IfModule>

</Directory>

# Authorize for setup
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
            AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
        </IfModule>
        Require valid-user
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/templates>
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

---

But still couldn't access `phpmyadmin` through browser.

Comment: Please show your phpmyadmin.conf once

Comment: Btw, when you are coming to the step in dpkg-reconfigure, where it asks you which server to use, click space after selecting `apache`

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana I have added `phpmyadmin.conf` file.

Comment: Be sure to backup your mysql databases before doing this (I am not responsible if you don't): Maybe just reinstall phpmyadmin using `sudo apt purge phpmyadmin && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt install phpmyadmin`.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana, **Yes** or **No**? `Configure database for phpmyadmin with dbconfig-common?`

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana I'm still getting **HTTP 500 Error** after reinstalling.

Comment: *Yes or No?* Yes

Comment: See the apache error log, you might find something interesting. OR enable display_errors in php.ini

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana I've created question which has error log https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65968090/valueerror-mb-convert-encoding-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: See my answer, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing is that it could be because the PHPMyAdmin version and the PHP version do not work together well.

You can see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65969268/12154890. I don't wanna post the same thing multiple times.